# Extracting multiple dataframes from a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, extract

I have a list of data frames, structured like this.

[image: list of dataframes]

I need to extract a variable number of elements from said list, and will just be joining them together using an identifier after I'm finished.

Extraction using the `[[]]` method works, but I cannot seem to get it to take a range.

This works:

```
x <- pf_metrics[[[1]]]
```

It extracts the entire first dataframe, in the original structure. This is what I would like to do, but across a variable length of dataframe lists.

Using syntax like...

```
x <- pf_metrics[c[1:length(pf_metrics)]]
```

OR

```
x <- pf_metrics[[c(1,2)]]
```

Doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to make them one dataframe ?

Comment: if you want a sublist you use `[]`.
if you want one element, you use `[[]]`
therefore, `x <- pf_metrics[c(1,2)]` will give you a sublist.

Comment: How about `pf_metrics[[1]][,c(1,2)]`?

Comment: Came up with a similar solution to below, none of the above will work here. do.call(what = rbind, args = pf_metrics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following -

```
num <- c(1, 2)
result <- dplyr::bind_rows(pf_metrics[num], .id = 'id')
```

where `num` are the list elements that you want to select and it will also include an `id` column which would be unique identifier of each list.

Comment: num is variable, will be a variable nuber of dataframes, so I dont think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
num <- c(1, 2)
result <- rbindlist(pf_metrics[num], idcol = 'id')
```